# How to use <New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property> to gather info on 2 foreach

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to aggregate the results of 2 foreach so I can run a nice report - this is the script:

```
$users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'TESTGRoup'
$result1 = ForEach ($user in $users){

    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
        User   = $user
        CN     = $User.SamAccountName
        Domain = $user.name
        Name   = $user.SID
    }
}

$Result4 = Get-ADGroupMember 'TESTGRoup' |
    Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq 'User'} |
    Get-AdUser |
    ForEach {
        Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName | Select UserprincipalName, Blockcredential  
        $result7 = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
            User1   = $Result4.UserPrincipalName
            CN1     = $Result4.BlockCredential
        }
    }
```

The end result is all the users joined up on a single line and not on a table.

Sorry for the code format - not sure how to present it better.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show a example of the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the below code will generate objects with the aggregated data you need on a single object per user:

```
#requires -Version 3
$results = foreach ($user in Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'TESTGRoup')
{
    $user | ? objectClass -eq User | Get-ADUser | % {
        $msol = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $PSItem.UserPrincipalName

        [pscustomobject]@{
            'User'   = $user
            'CN'     = $user.SamAccountName
            'Domain' = $user.Name
            'Name'   = $user.SID
            'User1'  = $msol.UserPrincipalName
            'CN1'    = $msol.BlockCredential
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Spot on! And now I understand how to build more CustomObjects from your example.